# Pivot Points + Auto Anchored VWAP

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to do an "auto-anchoring" VWAP, that will detect when a new Pivot Point (highest price in interval) is found, and re-load starting from that point.
The code I have so far is this:

```
//@version=3
study("Anchored VWAP2",overlay=true)


//calculating and plotting pivots


pvtLength = 20

pvtHigh = pivothigh(high, pvtLength, pvtLength)
pvtLow = pivotlow(low, pvtLength, pvtLength)

pvtHigh:= fixnan(pvtHigh)
pvtLow:= fixnan(pvtLow)
pvtHighColor = change(pvtHigh) != 0 ? na : maroon
pvtLowColor = change(pvtLow) != 0 ? na : green

plot(pvtHigh, color=pvtHighColor, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLength)
plot(pvtLow, color=pvtLowColor, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLength)
plot(pvtHigh, color=pvtHighColor, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=0)
plot(pvtLow, color=pvtLowColor, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=0)

//--------------------------------------------------------
//done with Pivot Points, now VWAP JOB (not working)
start = security(tickerid, '1', time)
newPivotHigh = change(pvtHigh) != 0 ? 1 : 0 //detect when new pivot is found
pivotTime = newPivotHigh ? time-(minute(time)-20) : na //grab the time when it occured (actual time less 20 minutes, because pivot length is always 20)
impulse_func = iff(time == pivotTime, 1, 0) //start plot only when the bar time is the pivot time
newSession = iff(newPivotHigh and change(start), 1, 0) //plot when current time changes and we have a new pivot
startSession = newSession * impulse_func
vwapsum = 0.0
volumesum = 0.0
myvwap = 0.0
vwapsum:= iff(startSession, high*volume, vwapsum[1]+high*volume)
volumesum:= iff(startSession, volume, volumesum[1]+volume)
myvwap:= vwapsum/volumesum
plot(myvwap, linewidth=3, transp=0, title='AVWAP')
```

Comment: So, what's your problem/question?

Comment: The code doesn't work. I need to anchor the VWAP on each new Pivot Point... It don't work.

Answer (score 0):

i just worked on this a little bit... the only issue i'm running into is getting the VWAP to start at the actual pivot point, not 20 bars ahead... added some debug stuff in there for you as well if you're looking at the ETHUSD chart. Also made it look at the close instead of the high because that what i was looking for when i found this. Let me know if you figure it out, i'm sure its not to hard, just cant think of a way right now.

```
//@version=3
study("Pivot Anchored VWAP",overlay=true)


//calculating and plotting pivots


pvtLength = input(20)

barcalc = pvtLength * 2500 // 1 minute is 2500 unix. 3,600,000 in a day.

pvtHigh = pivothigh(close, pvtLength, pvtLength)
pvtLow = pivotlow(close, pvtLength, pvtLength)

pvtHigh:= fixnan(pvtHigh)
pvtLow:= fixnan(pvtLow)
pvtHighColor = change(pvtHigh) != 0 ? na : maroon
pvtLowColor = change(pvtLow) != 0 ? na : green

plot(pvtHigh, color=pvtHighColor, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLength)
//plot(pvtLow, color=pvtLowColor, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLength)
//plot(pvtHigh, color=pvtHighColor, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=0)
//plot(pvtLow, color=pvtLowColor, transp=0, linewidth=1, offset=0)



start = security(tickerid, '1', time)
newPivotHigh = change(pvtHigh) != 0 ? 1 : 0 //detect when new pivot is found
pivotTime = newPivotHigh ? time - barcalc : na // calculate in unix instead of minutes, easier to change pivot length that way
impulse_func = iff(time == pivotTime, 1, 0) //start plot only when the bar time is the pivot time
newSession = iff(newPivotHigh and change(start), 1, 0) //plot when current time changes and we have a new pivot



test = iff(time >= pivotTime and time[1] < pivotTime, 1, 0)

pvtvwapstart = iff(time >= pivotTime and time[1] < pivotTime, 1, 0)
pvtvwapsumSrc = close * volume 
pvtvwapsumVol = volume
pvtvwapsumSrc := pvtvwapstart ? pvtvwapsumSrc : pvtvwapsumSrc + pvtvwapsumSrc[1]
pvtvwapsumVol := pvtvwapstart ? pvtvwapsumVol : pvtvwapsumVol + pvtvwapsumVol[1]
pvtVWAP = pvtvwapsumSrc/pvtvwapsumVol
 

plot(newPivotHigh + 228, color=white) ///debug plot when looking at ETHUSD


plot(pvtVWAP, title="Pivot Anchored VWAP", color=red, linewidth=1, transp=45)
```